# JSF view not recuperating data from database

Tags: hibernate, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database and get it into a JSF view in a datatable but there's an `Exception` problem I can't solve. I copied the necessary jars into lib folder and here is the list:

- jsf-api.jar
- jsf-impl.jar
- jstl-api-1.2.jar
- jstl-impl-1.2.jar

Here is the code of the JSF View: listFournisseur.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css"/>
</head>

<h:body>
<h:form>
<h:dataTable  var="fournisseur" value="#{fournisseurBean.listFournisseurs}" border="1">
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputLabel value="nom" />
</f:facet>
#{fournisseur.nomfour}
</h:column>
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputLabel value="raison sociale" />
</f:facet>
#{fournisseur.raisonsfour}
</h:column>
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputLabel value="Adresse" />
</f:facet>
 #{fournisseur.adressef}
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the code of the ManagedBean :FournisseurBean.java

```
package com.fst.bibliotheque.beans;

import java.util.List;

import com.fst.bibliotheque.dao.FournisseurHome;
import com.fst.bibliotheque.persistance.Fournisseur;
import com.fst.bibliotheque.services.FournisseurService;

public class FournisseurBean {

private FournisseurService gestionFournisseur;
private List<Fournisseur> listFournisseurs;
    private int tailleListe;

public List<Fournisseur> getListFournisseurs() {

    if(gestionFournisseur==null)
        gestionFournisseur=new FournisseurService();
    listFournisseurs=gestionFournisseur.findAllList();
    tailleListe=listFournisseurs.size();
    return listFournisseurs;

}

public void setListFournisseurs(List<Fournisseur> listFournisseurs) {
    this.listFournisseurs = listFournisseurs;
}


    }
```

Finally here is the code associated to the layer's service: FournisseurServices.java where is situated the methode responsable for retrieving data.

```
package com.fst.bibliotheque.services;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import com.fst.bibliotheque.dao.FournisseurHome;
import com.fst.bibliotheque.dao.HibernateUtil;

public class FournisseurService {

private FournisseurHome dao;

public FournisseurService() { dao = new FournisseurHome() ; }

public List findAllList() { 

    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession(); 
    Transaction tx= null ;
    List l=null;
    try{ 
        tx=session.beginTransaction(); 
        l=dao.findAll(); 
        tx.commit() ; 
        }catch(RuntimeException ex){
            if(tx!= null) tx.rollback();
            ex.printStackTrace() ; }
return l;   
}

}
```

The function findAllList() calls the findAll() function situated in the dao's layer:
Fournisseurdao.java:

```
package com.fst.bibliotheque.dao;

// Generated Dec 7, 2013 2:15:19 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import java.util.List;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.LockMode;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Order;

import com.fst.bibliotheque.persistance.Fournisseur;

import static org.hibernate.criterion.Example.create;

/**
* Home object for domain model class Fournisseur.
* @see com.fst.bibliotheque.dao.Fournisseur
* @author Hibernate Tools
*/
public class FournisseurHome {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(FournisseurHome.class);

private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();

protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    try {
        return HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI", e);
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI");
    }
}

public List findAll () { 
    Criteria crit     =sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Fournisseur.class);
    return crit.list();
}
public List findAll (Order defaultOrder) { 
    Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Fournisseur.class);
    if (null != defaultOrder) crit.addOrder(defaultOrder);
    return crit.list();
}
}
```

After the execution, I got this exception:

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/BibliothequeJSFHib1] threw exception [org/hibernate/Session] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session
```

does any one have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your FournisseurService - Class tries to open a Hibernate-Session.

```
public class FournisseurService {
    public List findAllList() { 
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession(); 
        ...
    }
}
```

Hibernate Session, an ORM-Mapper (Database-Stuff), is part of the [Hibernate-Core](http://hibernate.org/orm/) Library and has to be added to your project.

Comment: In fact i created a library in which i added hibernate jar's..i removed this library and copied the jars into the folder lib and the problem is solved :) thx alot.